# MySQL server has gone away with max_allowed_packet increased

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm trying to import csv file in phpmyadmin, but get an error #2006 Mysql server has gone away.

I have wait_timeout variable value 28800 (checked it from MySQL console)
In my.ini I had set it to 60000, but it didn't change. After restart SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout' gives me value of 28800.

I tried to set it through 'set session' and 'set global', tried to import again and get the #2006 error.

I have wamp on Windows 8.1. Tried to restart - doesn't help. Also, i have changed my max_allowed_packet to 128M.

Thoughts that it could be because of wait_timeout is that phpmyadmin is working for about 28.8 seconds before to show an error.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: specify in my.ini

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout = 60000;
```

probably wait_timeout is got to be here, but i'm not sure.
For the man, who voted this question down, if you read this - better tell the right answer next time...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your PHP/Apache time out window, i always have weird issues.

Open up your php.ini and look for your timeout settings

Also check the following link, since your running WAMP there can be some database issues:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Could you tell exactly what to do?

Comment: I will try it, by since I have time out in phpmyadmin 28.8 seconds and my wait_timeout value is 28800, i think i need to change this wait_timeout value, but don't know how and where.

Comment: If i knew how to private message on this site i would do that but! Do you have dreamweaver or atom?

Comment: Hm... Im running mac so im not sure where it is. Uhhh look up WAMP wait_timeout

Comment: After set interactive_timeout - the issue has gone. Seems like some start scripts use this interactive_timeout instead of wait_timeout...